# ASP.NET/MVC Opposite of isUserInRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I was wondering if there's a way of calling `isUserInRole` method like "ifUserIsNotInRole" or something iike that

Here's what I'm trying to do but the opposite of that.

```
@if (User.IsInRole"(Member"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean

`if (!User.IsInRole('otherrole'))` ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!